# Monitor bluetooth commands sent by my laptop

Tags: bluetooth

is there any software from which I can track which command is triggering from my Window 7, 64 bit laptop Bluetooth to control another device

Answer (score 1):

Probably [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) could be very useful, nothing escapes you.

Since the Wireshark system is large and vast, it deserves an equally large and extensive explanation. So it will not be enough a short example, but I can refer to the official guide ([how to capture Bluetooth traffic](https://wiki.wireshark.org/Bluetooth) that is well documented and with patience you can get good results.

Comment: Please detail the steps to filter Bluetooth, thanks! A screenshot showing that would be great too, and also please mention that it is free/open source, that will make your answer all the better :-)

Comment: "Please detail the steps to filter Bluetooth" - isn't that asking a bit much? It's fist time I ever heard such a request on this site. Will we expect it from all answers? I know that WireShark can do (I came here to post it as an answer); you probably do too. Is it too much to ask the OP to meet us half-way and learn to use the app which we recommend?